# Changing UI of jquery Datepicker in If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How to change the background color of the `a` in datepicker of jquery in `if statement` Here in my code, I have statement that if `if statement` is true the date will be disabled, but I want to change the background colro of `a` in datepicker instead of disabling. Please help me out of this problem, tyia.

//here's the script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // var unavailableDates = ["18-8-2018", "19-8-2018", "20-8-2018"]; // sample dates in day month year format


    var unavailableDates = <?php echo $jsonencode; ?>; // array from the condition above
    console.log(unavailableDates);

    function unavailable(date) {


        // ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();

                                // +1  because array starts at index 0 
                                //  without + 1 january will start on index 0 instead of index 1
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

        // to check if dmy exists in the variable array
        // inArray default result will be -1 meaning true. to reverse != -1
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) 
        {

            return [true, ""];

            // if true dates that exist in the array will be disabled
        } 
        else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"]; 
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { // to load jquery after the whole page loads
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'd-m-yy', // date format that would display on the textbox 
            //mindate = start of date  from current
            minDate: 0, 
            // to disable specific date unavailable function is called
            beforeShowDay: unavailable // function unavailable

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

datepicker

```
<input id="datepicker" name="dates" readonly='true'>
```

reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datejs/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="datejs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="datejs/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
```

To this:

```
return [true, "different-background", "Unavailable"];
```

And then you can style the `different-background` class however you like:

```
<style> .different-background a { background-color: red !important; } </style>
```

Comment: thankyou so much dude, Godbless you always!! MY TOGA IS WAITING HAHAHAHA THANKYOUUUUUUU!!!!!